# stored procedure doesn't return control to C# code

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am experiencing very strange issue: the stored procedure doesn't return even though the data is properly and timely inserted. The most staggering thing about this is that the record time stamp field is always populated within milliseconds so the data seems getting into the tables very fast. But return never happens.

Important part of all this is that it only happens under the load -- individual requests are just fine. Only when DB is stressed enough, this thing starts happening.

Any ideas are welcome because I have very little understanding what can be wrong.

Here is simplified C# part of it:

```
try 
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn, ....)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // THIS NEVER EXECUTES:
            ReportSuccess();
        }
    }
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    // EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

And the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Blah
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES (...)

    INSERT dbo.MyTable2...

    -- Here is where everything stops.

END
```

UPDATE: we did out best to correlate timeouts and SQL server activity and it appears non-app user activity was causing locks. The process is designed to allow very quick inserts and very quick reads. However some individuals would execute quite expensive queries without actually using DIRTY READ policy, which was tipping over the fragile hardware load balance. Thanks for all your tips though.

Comment: There is no return of any value. By return I mean SP never returns and exception is caught on C# side.

Comment: You mean ExecuteNonQuery() hangs?

Comment: @Maciej TimeoutException

Comment: have you tried to debug your sproc in ssms?

Comment: possible that the tables are locked by another process/transaction?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Maciej Hold on. I have to take it back. The exception is not really caught for ExectuteNonQuery. It eventually returns but timeout occurs for the SQL connection itself. I'll edit the question body.

Comment: How long is the timeout?

Comment: @JohnSaunders timeout on connection string is 30 seconds.

Comment: @DanielA.White debug when?

Comment: @Schultz9999 in sql management studio. see how long it takes in there.

Comment: Are you absorbing potential errors in your catch statement? Try removing the try/catch to see if the process blows up.

Comment: Where are you setting the cmd.CommandText ?

Comment: @Sam try-catch exists but is not empty -- there is plenty of logging happening inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, my best guess is that there is a contingency problem in your stored procedure.

Try using transaction in your stored procedure. If my theory is correct, no record will be inserted.

Check if there are any locks being acquired on MyTable2. If you doing a big select on that table elsewhere, ensure you are using nolock.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. If the data IS inserted then what's preventing the SP from returning? Because the SP is literary one INSERT statement. The second INSERT about was a debug one just to make sure the first one is fully executed. In fact we added two more inserts and they all successfully created records with good datetime values.

Comment: there is no next line. Main INSERT followed by a controlled one into a different table.

Comment: strange !! ok, then what is the exception being thrown, is it caught in your inner catch or outer catch?

Comment: No inner catch -- my fault in presenting the question. Removed and clarified.

Comment: There could be two reason why timeout could happen 1. if the query never returned 2. if the connection closing timeout (implicitly handled by using scope). you can confirm this by having an inner exception like before and see where the exception is being caught

Comment: I agree with kpadmanabhan. My money is on the fact that the code is not using transactions. It is trying to do an update/insert and under load there is blocking or deadlocking happening. I think this problem can be resolved by using a transaction. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx.

Comment: I surely can try but a single INSERT statement is atomic from SQL Server perspective so it should not create any contention whatsoever.